# Keras ImageDataGenerator brightness range

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, image-augmentation

In the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) for Keras `ImageDataGenerator`, there is reference to an arg called `brightness_range` (default `None`). The documentation says that this arg accepts

> Tuple or list of two floats. Range for picking a brightness shift value from.

That is extremely ambiguous. Does it mean a float within range (0,255)? Or does it mean a float within range (0,1)? The lack of specificity suggests that both would work, but I don't know how this tool is meant to be used. Is there any further documentation out there or general best practices for using this arg?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/exploring-image-data-augmentation-with-keras-and-tensorflow-a8162d89b844) shows, `0` means no brightness (completely black), `1` means maximum brightness (no change), and anything above just makes the image brighter.